# Extra line produced by \Needspace

Tags: spacing, line-breaking, page-breaking, line-spacing

I want to prevent page break for theorem environment if it contains less than 3 lines of text. I found that [`needspace`](https://ctan.org/pkg/needspace) package is what allows to do so by reserving specified space or break the page before.

Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{needspace}

\newtheorem{thr}{Theorem}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{thr}{\Needspace{3\baselineskip}}

\begin{document}

\section{name}

\begin{thr}
lorem ipsum
\end{thr}

\begin{thr}
lorem ipsum
\end{thr}

\end{document}
```

The problem that I faced with is an extra space (rather an extra line) that `\Needspace` puts between `thr`s, but right after `\section` it doesn't.

[image]

---

I looked up the source code and `\Needspace` defines like so

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Needspace}[1]{\par \penalty-100\begingroup
\setlength{\dimen@}{#1}%
\dimen@ii\pagegoal \advance\dimen@ii-\pagetotal
\ifdim \dimen@>\dimen@ii
\ifdim \dimen@ii>\z@
\vfil
\fi
\break
\fi\endgroup}
\makeatother
```

As you can see, it has `\par` at the beginning, but removing it doesn't solve the problem, but if you remove whole `\par \penalty-100`, then an extra space between `thr`s now is gone, but a new problem arrives: if `\section` is being carried to the new page if `thr` follows it then it a page break happens again

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{needspace}

\newtheorem{thr}{Theorem}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Needspace}[1]{\begingroup
\setlength{\dimen@}{#1}%
\dimen@ii\pagegoal \advance\dimen@ii-\pagetotal
\ifdim \dimen@>\dimen@ii
\ifdim \dimen@ii>\z@
\vfil
\fi
\break
\fi\endgroup}
\makeatother

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{thr}{\Needspace{3\baselineskip}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-5]

\section{name}

\begin{thr}
lorem ipsum
\end{thr}

\begin{thr}
lorem ipsum
\end{thr}

\end{document}
```

---

### So my question is how to fix the extra line that `\Needspace` creates, and prevent the bug I've just described above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The penalty changes `\lastskip` and then the next `\addvspace` behave differently. You could try to use the commands hyperref uses to avoid such problems:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{needspace}

\newtheorem{thr}{Theorem}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginEnvironment{thr}{\Hy@SaveLastskip\Needspace{3\baselineskip}\Hy@RestoreLastskip}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{name}

\begin{thr}
lorem ipsum
\end{thr}

\begin{thr}
lorem ipsum
\end{thr}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, that's what I was thinking of too. Tried to google "_undo /par_" and similar, but with no luck. Thank you!