# Difference between \addvspace and \vspace

Tags: spacing

I don't believe I'm the first person to ask this, but I really didn't find this question by searching.

In the definition of `\LaTeX` it used `\addvspace` and I usually use `\vspace` to add vertical space. So this made me wonder about their difference.

Comment: `\vspace` adds the space to the space immediately above (unless you are at the top of the page if you are not using the starred version), while `\advspace` does so only if there is no space above, or If there is a space above, it checks whether the space above is bigger or smaller than the space you want to add and only if "your" space is bigger than the space above it scraps the above space and inserts your new space.

Comment: @Lupino Could you provide an answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To understand the difference between `\vspace` and `\addvspace`, let's take a look into the definitions of both macros (from Texlive 2022's `latex.ltx`):

## `\vspace`

`\vspace` is defined as

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\vspace{\@ifstar\@vspacer\@vspace}
```

with a distinction between the starred (`\@vspacer`) and the non-starred version (`\@vspace`).

### unstarred version

The non-starred versio is defined as

```
\def\@vspace #1{%
  \ifvmode
    \@vspace@calcify{#1}%
    \vskip\z@skip
  \else
    \@bsphack
    \vadjust{\@restorepar
             \@vspace@calcify{#1}%
             \vskip\z@skip
            }%
    \@esphack
  \fi}
```

What's happening here is that we first look if we are in vertical mode (`\ifvmode`).

If we are in horizontal mode (i.e., we are within a paragraph), then we tell LaTeX to wait for the current line to be rendered (`\vadjust`) and then we execute the same code as we do when we were in vertical mode:

```
\@vspace@calcify{#1}%
\vskip\z@skip
```

The macro `\@vspace@calcify{#1}%` is defined elsewhere as

```
\def\@vspace@calcify#1{\begingroup\setlength\skip@{#1}\vskip\skip@\endgroup}
```

Here, we temporarily (`\begingroup...\endgroup`) set a length register (`\setlength\skip@`) to the amount defined in the argument to `\vspace` (`#1`) and call the primitive `\vskip` with that register as argument (`\vskip\skip@`) to insert the vertical skip into the output stream. The setting of the temporary macro is done, so the macros from the `calc` package can be used witin `#1`.

The second line, `\vskip\z@skip` adds a zero length (`\z@skip=0pt plus0pt minus0pt`) after the actual skip. This is done to prevent the `\removelastskip` macro to consume the vertical skip we explicitly want to be there.

(we're gonna ignore `\@bsphack`, `\@esphack` and `\@restorepar` since they are irrellevant for the question)

### starred version

`\vspace*` is defined as

```
\def\@vspacer#1{%
  \ifvmode
    \dimen@\prevdepth
    \hrule \@height\z@
    \nobreak
    \@vspace@calcify{#1}%
    \vskip\z@skip
    \prevdepth\dimen@
  \else
    \@bsphack
    \vadjust{\@restorepar
             \hrule \@height\z@
             \nobreak
             \@vspace@calcify{#1}%
             \vskip\z@skip}%
    \@esphack
  \fi}
```

It is basicly the same, but with one important addition: We add a rule of zero height (and width) before the skip (`\hrule \@height\z@`). With that, we force LaTeX into horizontal mode and, whilst preventing a potential page break (`\nobreak`), we immediately go back into vertical mode (this is done automatically with `\vskip`). This has the following effect: assume, we are at the very top of the page and in vertical mode. In this specific context,  vskips usually do not apply. Now, by "breaking" the vertical mode, TeX is no longer "at the very top" of the type area (since there is hmode-stuff between the actual top and the current position, albeit *empty* hmode-stuff). Therefore, the vskip *is* applied.

With the second addition, `\dimen@\prevdepth` and later `\prevdepth\dimen@` when in vertical mode, we "move" the information on whether or not we were at the top of the type area, to the stuff that comes after the `\vspace*` ("slightly" simplified).

## `\addvspace`

`\addvspace` is defined as

```
\def\addvspace#1{%
  \ifvmode
     \if@minipage\else
       \ifdim \lastskip =\z@
         \@vspace@calcify{#1}%
       \else
         \setlength\@tempskipb{#1}%
         \@xaddvskip
       \fi
     \fi
  \else
    \@noitemerr
  \fi}
```

At first, we look if we are in vertical mode, and throw an error, if we are not. Here, we have the first real difference between `\vspace` and `\addvspace`: `\addvspace` can only be used in vertical mode, while `\vspace` can be used in both vertical *and horizontal* modes.

The second conditional (`\if@minipage`) checks whether we are at the top of a `minipage` environment. Since the "true" branch is empty, any `\addvspace` does nothing. Second difference.

The third conditional is `\ifdim \lastskip =\z@`, which checks if the last vertical skip (which is stored in `\lastskip`) is 0pt (`\z@`). If so, we apply the `\@vspace@calcify{#1}` macro we already know.

Hoewver, if there is a non-zero vertical skip before the `\addvspace`, we store the argument in a temporary length register `\@tempskipb` and call the macro `\@xaddvskip`, which is defined as

```
\def\@xaddvskip{%
  \ifdim\lastskip<\@tempskipb
    \vskip-\lastskip
    \vskip\@tempskipb
  \else
    \ifdim\@tempskipb<\z@
      \ifdim\lastskip<\z@
      \else
        \advance\@tempskipb\lastskip
        \vskip-\lastskip
        \vskip \@tempskipb
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi}
```

Here, we check if the stored length is larger than the last skip (`\ifdim\lastskip<\@tempskipb`). If yes, then we remove that last skip (`\vskip-\lastskip`) and add our temporary skip instead (`\vskip\@tempskipb`).

If the last skip is larger than our temporary skip, we check if either or  both the temporary and the last skips are negative.

If the temporary skip is negative and the lastskip is negative, we do nothing. This means, that only the last skip prevails and the amount we provided with `\addvspace` is discarded. The same happens when both values are positive, but our temporary value is still smaller than the last skip's value (since there is no `\else` branch in the `\ifdim\@tempskipb<\z@` conditional).

If our temporary skip is negative and the last skip is positive, we add the value of the last skip to our temporary skip (`\advance\@tempskipb\lastskip`), remove the whole last skip (`\vskip-\lastskip`), and then we insert a vertical skip with the new value of our temporary skip (`\vskip \@tempskipb`). For example, if the last skip was `10pt` and we add `\addvspace{-3pt}`, then we get a vertical skip of `-3pt + 10pt = 7pt`.

Note that there is no `\vskip\z@skip` in the definition of `\addvspace`, which means that `\removelastskip` *does* affect skips inserted with `\addvspace`, which is another difference between `\addvspace` and `\vspace`.

You might also note that the definition of `\@xaddvskip` lacks a call to `\@vspace@calcify`. The sole purpose of this intermediate function was to pass the argument of the skip through `\setlength` so that the macros from the `calc` package (which hook into `\setlength`) can be used within the argument. We already did that before we called `\@xaddvskip`, when we set `\@tempskipb` to the argument's value, so that additional step is not necessary.

## tl;dr

- `\vspace{X}` adds `X` amount of vertical space, `\addvspace{Z}` checks if there is a vertical space `Y` immediately above `\addvspace{Z}` and only adds `Z` if `Z>Y`, or if `Y=0pt`.
- if `Z<0pt` and `Y>0pt`, `Z+Y` is added as vertical space
- `\addvspace` at the top of a `minipage` environment does do nothing, while `\vspace` does do spaces.
- `\vspace` can be used in vertical and horizontal mode, `\addvspace` only in vertical mode
- skips added with `\addvspace` can be removed by `\removelastskip`, skips added with `\vspace` cannot.

### One final note regarding "last skip"

As we figured out, `\addvspace` takes into account the "skip before" itself by comparing the value in its argument with the value of `\lastskip`. However, there are some contexts where `\lastskip` might be disturbed by other commands (e.g., [`\write`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/651590/preserve-vertical-lastskip-over-write?noredirect=1#comment1661036_651590) and [`\penalty`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/651348/extra-line-produced-by-needspace)), more specificly commands that add non-glues to the vertical list, even though they don't produce any visible output. In those cases, the amount of `\addvspace` is plainly *added* to the already existing vertical skip and you might end up with much larger spaces than you would elsewhere.

Comment: addvspace does work in minipage, the test is for the top of a minipage to emulate top of a page, where space is dropped `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{3cm}
  aaa
\par
\addvspace{2cm}
bbb
\end{minipage}}
\end{document}`

Comment: "spuriously disturbed by other macros" `\write` and `\penalty` are not macros, they make nodes in the vertical list so affect `\lastskip` in the same way as the `\rule` case you describe. `\lastskip` only has a non zero value if the last node is a glue node.

Comment: you mean `\addvspace` not `\addvskip` in some places.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks for the clarificaton; I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Right, thanks. I've corrected the occurences.