# Distance between minted environment and text and section

Tags: environments, minted, technical-environment

I'm using `minted` and somehow the distance between the minted environment and the text around or the (sub)section are not the same and vary too much from normal spacing.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}   
\usepackage{minted}
\newminted{py}{bgcolor=gray!5, breaklines = true,gobble=0,  fontfamily=courier}
\newmintinline[picode]{python}{}

\newcounter{ea}[subsubsection]
\newenvironment{ea}[1][]{\refstepcounter{ea}\par\medskip
\noindent \textit{Example~\theea. #1} \rmfamily}{\medskip}
\begin{document}
\section{Sample}
\subsection{Sample 1}
The code goes here: 

\begin{ea}
\begin{pycode}
440//11
40
117//5
23
\end{pycode}
\end{ea}
%THIS DISTANCE IS TOO MUCH
\subsection{range()}
\begin{ea}
\begin{pycode}
for i in range(2): 
    print(i)
#Output
0 
1
\end{pycode}
\end{ea} 
Some text goes here
\subsection{Unknown}

\end{document}
```

Here is it on image:

[image]

With, or without the text after the environment ea, it seems that the distance between them are large. How can I fix that? I tried to set `framsep = 2pt` or `framesep=2mm` without success.

Comment: The problem comes from the `ea` environment. You only need to use `TEST` followed by an empty line instead of the `mint` environments to see this.

Comment: No, I tried, but the space are not the same. And `ea` environment worked perfectly with another tcblisting environment, so I think there must be a problem with `ea` and `minted`.

Comment: Please don't use the python tag just because you choose python as language for the syntax highlighting. Your question would be the same with any other language for the syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 4):

You don't want `\medskip`, but rather `\addvspace{\medskipamount}`. See [Difference between \addvspace and \vspace](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/668162/4427)

```
\documentclass{article}   
\usepackage{minted}

\newminted{py}{bgcolor=gray!5, breaklines = true,gobble=0,  fontfamily=courier}
\newmintinline[picode]{python}{}

\newcounter{ea}[subsubsection]
\newenvironment{ea}[1][]{\refstepcounter{ea}\par\addvspace{\medskipamount}
\noindent \textit{Example~\theea. #1} \rmfamily}{\par\addvspace{\medskipamount}}

\begin{document}

\section{Sample}

\subsection{Sample 1}

The code goes here: 

\begin{ea}
\begin{pycode}
440//11
40
117//5
23
\end{pycode}
\end{ea}

\subsection{range()}

\begin{ea}
\begin{pycode}
for i in range(2): 
    print(i)
#Output
0 
1
\end{pycode}
\end{ea} 

Some text goes here

\subsection{Unknown}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Don't complain about the larger space before the section title, because it's due to the larger font size in the title.

However, I'd use more standard methods.

```
\documentclass{article}   
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newminted{py}{bgcolor=gray!5, breaklines = true,gobble=0,  fontfamily=courier}
\AddToHook{env/pycode/before}{\leavevmode\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}
\newmintinline[picode]{python}{}

\newtheoremstyle{example}
  {\topsep}   % ABOVESPACE
  {\topsep}   % BELOWSPACE
  {\normalfont}  % BODYFONT
  {0pt}       % INDENT (empty value is the same as 0pt)
  {\itshape} % HEADFONT
  {.}         % HEADPUNCT
  {\newline} % HEADSPACE
  {\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}\thmnote{\/{\normalfont\space(#3)}}} % CUSTOM-HEAD-SPEC
\theoremstyle{example}
\newtheorem{ea}{Example}[subsection]

\begin{document}

\section{Sample}

\subsection{Sample 1}

The code goes here: 

\begin{ea}
\begin{pycode}
440//11
40
117//5
23
\end{pycode}
\end{ea}

\subsection{range()}

\begin{ea}[Interesting]
\begin{pycode}
for i in range(2): 
    print(i)
#Output
0 
1
\end{pycode}
\end{ea} 

Some text goes here

\subsection{Unknown}

Some text

\begin{pycode}
for i in range(2): 
    print(i)
#Output
0 
1
\end{pycode}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer egreg, however, I do want sth like this, which I got from using `ea` environment with tcbox. 

https://imgur.com/a/tvQrf0t